# PHP Dynamically added elements on Submit grab values

Tags: php, forms

**SOLVED**

I found he issue, while I was creating new ROW I was accidently grabbing the  tag and it was creating new form wrap every time I added the row.

So it ended up being:

form
Row 1
form 2
Row 2
form 3
Row 3
form END

I am trying to submit my form with dynamically added fields however I keep only getting the initial one.

**SetUp**

```
HTMLDOM

FORM<br/>
div->Item<br/>
--Input<br/>
--SelectOption<br/>
--TextArea<br/>
--RadioButton<br/>
div->Item(EndWrap)
```

I have jQuery Grab initial wrap into a variable, once I click ADD ROW elements get +1 count.

I have tried the following on form Submit:

```
foreach ($_POST['user'] as $key=>$value ) {
    echo $key . " : " . $value;
}

<input id="user" type="text" name="user[]" autocomplete="off"/>
```

However that only shows me the user of the first ITEM -> Wrap or ROW.

My question would be what is the best way to iterate over dynamically added elements inside the form on submission so that I can add values to the DB.

Thank you!
Even a direction to a `valid` tutorial will be greatly appreciated (had no luck finding any that work).

Comment: I am afraid that your query is not much clear. Do you want to have all the values coming in `user[]` field(s) ?

Comment: No I have just shorten it for an example, lets say I have only 1 field instead of many.. How would i go over them. However I have Rows-> with many fields. Eg. Row 1 -> Name, Age, Sex, Description.. Than I would click Add New Row and have Row 2 -> Name, Age, Sex, Dec. However when I submit i only get first row results

Comment: @theStudent does your dynamically generated new row have unique `id` for all elements?

Comment: yes it goes like Row1->Name, Row2->Name2, Row3->Name3 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Match your code with the following one:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
        foreach ($_POST['user'] as $key=>$value ) {
            echo $key . " : " . $value."<br />";
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method='POST'>
            Val 1: <input id="user" type="text" name="user[]" autocomplete="off"/><br />
            Val 2: <input id="user" type="text" name="user[]" autocomplete="off"/><br />
            Val 3: <input id="user" type="text" name="user[]" autocomplete="off"/><br />
            Val 4: <input id="user" type="text" name="user[]" autocomplete="off"/>
            <input type="submit" name="sub"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is working for me. Although, the ids must not be same for all fields but I am taking same as per your case.

Comment: I found the issue, my dynamically added rows were also creating an new <form wrap>, it all works now ..

Comment: Thats great, please approve my answer if it helped